# Converting spaces and brackets to unicode in query result

Tags: sql-server, xml, unicode, cross-apply

I am using an CROSS APPLY & and a custom-built XML function (instead UNPIVOT) in SQL Server 2012, to move values vertically within a table.

```
 SELECT A.USERID
    ,B.[ITEM]  
    ,B.VALUE 
 FROM #UPLOAD  A
CROSS APPLY [DBO].[TVF-XML-UNPIVOT-ROW]( (SELECT A.* FOR XML RAW) ) B
WHERE [ITEM] NOT IN ('USERID' )
```

The query successfully unpivots everything, but in the process, converts spaces, dashes, brackets, etc into their respective UNICODE value, as follows:

```
EMPID   ITEM                                                                            VALUE    
123     _x0027_October_x0020_Bonus_x0020__x0028_Perm_x0020__x002B__x0020_Temp_x0029_    28.01
```

Expected output:

```
 EMPID   ITEM                           VALUE    
 123     October Bonus (Perm + Temp)    28.01
```

Below is the function, some temp values you can use, and the Code itself. Any how to format the string without the unicode values?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-XML-UnPivot-Row](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return ( 
        Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
         From  @XML.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
)

DROP TABLE #UPLOAD
CREATE TABLE #UPLOAD (USERID INT,['October Bonus (Perm + Temp)] FLOAT NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO #UPLOAD VALUES  (123,20.3),(240,35) 

 SELECT A.USERID
    ,B.[ITEM]  
    ,B.VALUE 
 FROM #UPLOAD  A
CROSS APPLY [DBO].[TVF-XML-UNPIVOT-ROW]( (SELECT A.* FOR XML RAW) ) B
WHERE [ITEM] NOT IN ('USERID' )
```

Comment: Looks familiar :)  The JSON approach will handle the column names better

Comment: This is a known issue with the XML approach.   You've got some ugly names, and the only think I can think of is a series of replace()'s

Comment: Okay, good to know ! I'm getting the data from a business-managed excel file, only so much I can do about the column names.

Comment: Kinda figured that :)  This is why data people should rule the word.

Comment: Just to be clear.  XML is a little fussy about node & attribute names

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**  I recall now that you were NOT 2016+

If 2016+  You can use this function instead of the XML approach

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-JSON-Unpivot-Row](@json varchar(max))

Returns Table 
As Return

Select [Key]
      ,Value
 From OpenJson(@json)
```

**Examples**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.* 
 from  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-JSON-Unpivot-Row]( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) ) B
 Where [Key] not in ('ID')
```

or to include NULLs

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.* 
 from  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-JSON-Unpivot-Row]( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES  ) ) B
 Where [Key] not in ('ID')
```